# trying to scrape coinmarketcap and get "none"

Tags: python, web-scraping

im using python to build a basic script to **scrape** some data from coinmarketcap and i get none and i dont know why , an you help me please ?

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as S
import requests

c = input('enter your coin')
url = f'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/{c}/'

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup = S(r.content,'html.parser')

print(f'the price of {c} now is ')
x = soup.find(id="priceValue___11gHJ")
print(x)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and made some changes to make it work.

The field you want to get uses class instead of id.

Take a look at it.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as S
import requests

c = input('enter your coin')
url = f'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/{c}/'

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = S(r.content,'html.parser')
print(f'the price of {c} now is ')
x = soup.find(class_='priceValue___11gHJ').text
print(x)
```

Comment: thank you so much but i have question , why we use _ after class ? "class_"

Comment: It's a reserved keyword of the BeautifulSoup module.  Take a look at documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#:~:text=the%20keyword%20argument-,class_,-%3A

Comment: If you think the answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered. Thanks.